# Inclusion/Exclusion: How many natural numbers < 10,000,000 contain 168, in order, consecutively?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

For example, 1,683,718, but not 1,568.

I need to use the multiplication principle (which will produce overcounting) and the principle of inclusion/exclusion to find this (or a better way, if possible). Any pointers? The fixed 168 is what throws me off from typical problems.

Comment: What would you say if the problem asked for numbers < 10,000?

Comment: @Chris Culter I know that we can use the MP on the four digits. So you could have 168 in either 168X or X168. So in case 1, you have 1*1*1*10 = 10 numbers, and in Case 2, you have 10*1*1*1 numbers. So you have 20 different numbers?

Comment: Yep, now what about 100,000 and 1,000,000?

Comment: 5 digits,
XX168 - 10 * 10 * 1 * 1 * 1 = 100
X168X - 1 * 10 * 1 * 1 * 1 = 100
168XX - 1 * 1 * 1 * 10 * 10 = 100

For < 100,000 - 300 different numbers. So I could list them out like this all the way to 7 digits (<10,000,000), but is there a quicker way that specifically uses the Inclusion/Exclusion principle, or am I missing a concept?

Comment: You didn't need inclusion/exclusion for 4 and 5 digits, but you'll probably need it for 6 and 7. What would you say the answer is for 6 digits (<1,000,000)?

Comment: I found the answer for 7 digits to be 50,000.

XXXX168 will be 10,000 numbers, and each time I move the 168 to the left of that sequence, I get 10,000 more numbers.

Comment: That's incorrect. Trust me, you'll want to try 6 digits first. It's easier to see the problem there.

Comment: XXX168 has 10 * 10 * 10 = 1,000 numbers. Moving 168 to the left each time produces another 1,000 numbers. XXX168, XX168X, X168XX, 168XXX.

We'd be counting 168168 twice then?

Comment: Precisely, to correct for counting 168168 twice, you have to subtract 1 from the overestimate of 4,000.

Comment: Okay, I see where the duplicates come from. But how can I find the number to subtract off for 7 digits without listing them out individually?

Comment: Well, for 7 digits, some of the double-counted examples are of the form 168168X, some are of the form 168X168...

Comment: So you subtract off 20. Maybe I'm trying to follow the set definition of Inclusion/Exclusion too closely or something. I understand what you're explaining, but I am wondering if there was a different, more 'formal' approach other than listing out everything like we did.

Comment: ...and some are of the form X168168, so you subtract off 30! I'll address the set thing in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're counting the union of five sets: the strings of the form 168XXXX, the strings of the form X168XXX, etc. Each set has $10000$ elements. By inclusion-exclusion, you can sum these counts to $50000$ and subtract the counts of the pairwise intersections of the sets, which contain strings of the form 168168X, 168X168, and X168168, of which there are $30$. The intersections of three or more sets are all empty, so we are done, arriving at $50000-30=49970$.

To double-check, we can get the same answer by brute force:

```
$ python
>>> sum('168' in str(x) for x in range(10000))
20
>>> sum('168' in str(x) for x in range(100000))
300
>>> sum('168' in str(x) for x in range(1000000))
3999
>>> sum('168' in str(x) for x in range(10000000))
49970
```

Comment: I see the relation now to the definition and understand the approach, the code was a nice touch. Thank you very much for your time spent on this problem.